# How to get at event when overriding jquery event handlers

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var oldFocus = $.fn.focus;
$.fn.focus = function () {
    // how to get event here?
    return oldFocus.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

how can I get at the event object?

**Update:** using jquery 2.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.event.special.focus = {
    trigger: function(e){
        console.log(e);
        return false; // if false, focus is not firing
    }
};
```

Try this code.

**Edit by OP:**

pushOK's code is the starting point i needed. What i needed to achieve my objective detailed in the comments below was:

```
$.event.special.focus = {
    trigger: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: I realise I can do this, thanks. However thats not what I want. I need to override the default focus action.

Comment: @AndrewBullock what is the behaviour you are expetcing for?

Comment: I've got lots of code that calls .focus(). I want to prevent this from focusing the element when on a mobile device but I want any onfocus handlers to fire.

Comment: doesnt work. also that code doesnt seem to agree with the docs. http://jsfiddle.net/RR2Cr/1/

Comment: Please forgive me, wrote this code from my memory =) Updated. Work only with .focus() (only with events with no data in it) http://jsfiddle.net/RR2Cr/2/